# Ninject numa ClassLibrary e ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

Para entender vou expor o cenário. 
A aplicação utiliza o ninject com repositórios e services, porém, alguns models têm propriedades de navegação, tudo no mesmo projeto

No MVC existe o objecto DependencyResolver.Current.GetService 
que aponta para o ninject module (configurado pra isso).

Porém, precisamos migrar toda essa lógica para outro projeto, para reutilização, mas também minimizar a refatoração de código.

Numa class library, como eu faço para utilizar o ninject ?

O projeto principal será um MVC com uma class library. Como eu utilizo esse DependencyResolver na library?

Posso criar o kernel do Ninject e guardar ele numa variável estática?

```
private static Ninject.StandardKernel _kernel = null;

static DependencyResolver()
{
    _kernel = new Ninject.StandardKernel();
    _kernel.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

}
```

Fazer isso afetaria o funcionamento do ninject ?
Qual o melhor método para fazer isso?